# Are there different voices?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I've noticed in Guild Wars 2 that some of my characters have different voices even though they are the same race.

Is there more than one voice for each race/role combination? Does anyone know which voices go with which combinations?

Comment: When I created my character in GW2, I was presented with a selection of voices.  Each seemed like the same voice, just played back in a different pitch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you're mistaken, sorry to say. Each race only has one voice actor each for the male and female roles; they do not vary by class.

The voice cast is as follows:

- Human PC Male: Nolan North
- Human PC Female: April Stewart
- Charr PC Male: Ron Yuan
- Charr PC Female: Kate Miller
- Norn PC Male: Matthew Mercer
- Norn PC Female: Claudia Christian
- Asura PC Male: Steve Staley
- Asura PC Female: Julianne Buescher
- Sylvari PC Male: Brandon Bales
- Sylvari PC Female: Jennifer Hale

That list was taken from a forum post during beta that I saved on my PC, so unfortunately I can't link to that particular source anymore, but [this post](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/archive/story/I-hate-personal-stories-Did-I-fail-the-game/first#post1479428) (regarding the amount of resources they'd need for more voices) on the current live forums confirms it as well:

> 5 playable races x 2 genders = 10 character combinations / 10 voices

Comment: Nolan North as human??? That's awesome...